# How do I define a color when using AlphaBlend?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I have an image which is drawn onto a paintbox, I want to be able to show a translucent filled rectangle above any given area of the paintbox which will show the underneath paintbox canvas in a darker color, kind of like the selection box from Windows Explorer.

After much trial and error (and some reading), I managed to do the following:

```
procedure OpacityRectangle(ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; AColor: TColor;
  AOpacity: Integer);
var
  BlendFunc: BLENDFUNCTION;
  W, H: Integer;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  W := ARect.Width;
  H := ARect.Height;

  BlendFunc.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
  BlendFunc.BlendFlags := 0;
  BlendFunc.SourceConstantAlpha := AOpacity;
  BlendFunc.AlphaFormat := 0;

  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
    Bitmap.SetSize(W, H);    
    BitBlt(Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, ARect.Left + W, ARect.Top + H, W, H,
      ACanvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    AlphaBlend(ACanvas.Handle, ARect.Left, ARect.Top,
        W, H, Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, W, H, BlendFunc);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As you can see the `AColor` parameter is unused as I am unsure exactly as to how I would implement it above. Currently the color of the alpha blended rectangle is a shade of gray (default color I assume), I need to know how I can change the tint color of the alpha blended rectangle.

How could I modify the above to allow choosing a custom color for the tinted alpha blended rectangle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently you are using white, the reason you think it's gray is the translucency. You can verify it by passing 255 as 'AOpacity', you'll see a white rectangle.

The tint color is white because that's the color of your temporary bitmap. All you need to do is to use a colored bitmap. You should remove the `BitBlt` call, a solid color bitmap is sufficient to apply a tinted color when it is copied transparently to the destination canvas.

```
  ...
  try
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := AColor;  // <- set tint color
    Bitmap.SetSize(W, H);
    AlphaBlend(ACanvas.Handle, ARect.Left, ARect.Top,
      ...
```

---

In case of Lazarus, explicitly paint the bitmap surface, fpc graphics does not honor brush color when enlarging bitmap (hence the bitmap is initially black).

```
  ..
  try
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
    Bitmap.SetSize(W, H);
    Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := AColor;
    Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Bitmap.Canvas.ClipRect);
    AlphaBlend(ACanvas.Handle, ARect.Left, ARect.Top,
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and answer, unfortunately I did not realise I left the `Lazarus` tag out of the question (not your fault). In Lazarus this does not seem to work using `JwaWindows.AlphaBlend()` and right now I cannot test on Delphi, this is likely a issue with Lazarus but I will need to experiment some more.

Comment: @Craig - Verified. The issue is fpc graphics does not  use the brush color when resizing bitmap. Set size first, set brush color next, then insert a bitmap.canvas.fillrect with a rect(0, 0, W, H). Then it works.

Comment: Working perfectly now thanks Sertac, extra thanks for clarifying a few things too such as why I perceived the default alpha color was gray and why I didnt even need to use BitBlt.